# Webpack: Split dynamic imported modules into separate chunks while keeping the library in the main bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I am working on a web app containing widgets that should be lazily loaded using [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).
Each widget should receive its separate bundle for it and their dependencies to only be fetched by the browser once it is being requested by the user. There's an exception to this: Popular widgets should be included in the main bundle as well as the library classes they use or extend. Below you see the folder structure I intend to achieve and the output I aim for:

```
File Structure                       Desired chunk

src/
├── widgets/
│   ├── popular-widget/index.ts      main
│   ├── edge-case-widget/index.ts    edge-case-widget
│   └── interesting-widget/index.ts  interesting-widget
├── library/
│   ├── Widget.ts                    main
│   └── WidgetFactory.ts             main
└── index.ts                         main (incl. entry point)

dist/
├── edge-case-widget.app.js          edge-case-widget
├── interesting-widget.app.js        interesting-widget
└── main.app.js                      main (incl. entry point)
```

To lazily load widgets I am using following expression in a `create` method in `WidgetFactory`. This works fine, the widget modules get magically picked up by Webpack.

```js
const Widget = await import(`../widgets/${name}/index`)
```

I was trying to solve the code splitting challenge by configuring `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups` in Webpack. Providing a `test` function I allocate modules into either the `library` or `widgets` cache group.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  [...]
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        library: {
          test: module => isInLibrary(module.identifier()),
          name: 'library',
          chunks: 'all',
          minSize: 0
        },
        widgets: {
          test: module => isWidgetBundle(module.identifier()),
          name: module => widgetNameFromModuleId(module.identifier()),
          chunks: 'async',
          minSize: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am stuck!

- How can I include widget dependencies in the widget bundles?
- Using `chunks: 'async'` on the `library` cache group make some library classes go to the `main` chunk while others stay in the `library` chunk. Why?
- When I use `chunks: 'all'` on the `library` cache group all modules properly get combined in it but I lose the entry point on the `main` chunk and get a blank page. How?
- When I rename the `library` cache group to `main` I lose the entry point, [as documented here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname). I don't quite understand why this is the case and how I manage to combine the `main` entry point with the `library` into a single bundle.

Hopefully you can shed some light onto my steep learning curve with Webpack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

created a simple github [repo](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-split-example) with configuration you need.

1. SplitChunks configuration (change `test` and `name` functions to yours if you want):

```
    splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                widgets: {
                    test: module => {
                        return module.identifier().includes('src/widgets');
                    },
                    name: module => {
                        const list = module.identifier().split('/');
                        list.pop();
                        return list.pop();
                    },
                    chunks: 'async',
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
    }
```

2. If you want PopularWidget to be in `main`, you should not import it dynamically. Use regular `import` statement. Because webpack will ALWAYS create a new chunk for any dynamic import. So please take a look at [this](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-split-example/blob/master/src/library/WidgetFactory.ts) file.

```
    import { Widget } from '../widgets/popular-widget';

    export class WidgetFactory {
        async create(name) {
            if (name === 'popular-widget') return await Promise.resolve(Widget);
            return await import(`../widgets/${name}/index`)
        }
    }
```

UPD
Changed configuration to keep related node_modules with widgets.
I wrote two simple functions for new widgets chunk creation.
The trick here is `module.issuer` property which means who imported this file. So function `isRelativeToWidget` will return true for any dependencies (node_modules or not) imported at any depth of widget's file structure.
Code can be found [here](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-split-example/blob/master/webpack.config.js).
Resulting configuration:

```
splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: false,
                default: false,
                edgeCaseWidget: getSplitChunksRuleForWidget('edge-case-widget'),
                interestingWidget: getSplitChunksRuleForWidget('interesting-widget')
            }
        }

function isRelativeToWidget(module, widgetName) {
    if (module.identifier().includes(widgetName)) return true;

    if (module.issuer) return isRelativeToWidget(module.issuer, widgetName)
}

function getSplitChunksRuleForWidget(widgetName) {
    return {
        test: module => isRelativeToWidget(module, widgetName),
        name: widgetName,
        chunks: 'async',
        enforce: true,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Switching between direct and dynamic import in the factory works perfectly! Now assuming the Edge Case Widget needs an NPM library, the current Webpack config creates a separate bundle for it. Do you see any way to let Webpack include dependencies of a widget inside the same bundle?

Comment: @ffraenz I will take a look how to handle it tomorrow morning

Comment: Yes, `module.issuer` is definitely the right call. I guess it needs some tweaking to handle Core JS but I'll get that one sorted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to what I usually use in my Webpack (v4) configuration, I'd configure it this way:

```
splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'async',
    minSize: 30000,
    minChunks: 1,
    maxAsyncRequests: 5,
    maxInitialRequests: 3,
    name: true,
    cacheGroups: {
        default: {
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        library: {
            test: module => module => isInLibrary(module.identifier()),
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true
        },
    }
}
```

If widgets are only required lazily, do not add `widgets` to the cacheGroups.

Webpack should resolve the widget dependencies in library for each async require.

I didn't try forcing bundle names but I think it will behave the same.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested. `src/library/Widget.ts` gets extended by each widget module and thus gets bundled multiple times. Is there any chance to get such modules moved to the main bundle instead?

Comment: I think I read it backward. Widget are loaded lazily by main and depend on library so try and keep library in cacheGroup and remove widget from it. I've updated the answer. widgets should not be bundled in main if they're only required lazily.

Comment: Yes, widgets are only imported dynamically. After updating the Webpack config I ran into multiple issues: (1) The library chunk is now separated again from the main chunk. (2) The widget class mentioned in my first comment receives an own chunk instead of being added to the main chunk. (3) Obviously the widget bundles are no longer named. Isn't my use case valid for the cache groups strategy?